# Get VBscript results on One line

Tags: vbscript

I try to get all printers installed on the computer using VBScript, when I run this VBScript I get the last printer (I have many printers), how can I show all the printers on one line?

The resultant pic

[image]

```
Function Printers
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer",,48) 
For each objItem in colItems
Printers = objItem.Name
Next
End Function
WScript.Echo "Printers: " &  Printers
```

I need the result like the pic below

[image]

Comment: Concatenate the `Printers` string in the `For` loop or you will only get the last iterations result. Something like `Printers = Printers & "; " & objItem.Name` should work.

Answer (score 0):

When using a `For` loop any variable assigned inside the loop is replaced during the next iteration, as this is a string you can just keep concatenating the result of each iteration to the next.

```vb
'Make sure all variables are properly declared.
Option Explicit

Function Printers
    Dim items: items = ""
    Dim strComputer: strComputer  = "."
    Dim objWMIService : Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Dim colItems: Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer",,48) 
    Dim objItem

    For Each objItem in colItems
        'Concatenate each string to the next.
        items = items & "; " & objItem.Name
    Next
    'Assign return value
    Printers = items
End Function

WScript.Echo "Printers: " &  Printers
```